# Python 2.7 with Adwords API: ImportError: cannot import name AdWordsClient

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm getting the following error when I try to use Adwords  API with Python 2.7 in a Windws 7:
ImportError: cannot import name AdWordsClient

with the following code (I got it from google examples):

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join('..', '..', '..', '..', '..'))

# Import appropriate classes from the client library.
from adspygoogle import AdWordsClient
from adspygoogle.common import Utils
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the full traceback / error message. Thank you.

Comment: I already solved the problem. I imported the library fpconst.

Answer (score 1):

Already solved. Just add the line in the start of code:

```
import fpconst
```